# My coreData does not load before the view gets called in my init() method

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am using this method to set values of state to values in my coreData entity UserSettings so I can display them on the screen.

The most common method of fetching coreData entities is with the fetch request, but for some reason, it does not load in the values and says the array is empty:

ProfileView:

```
import HealthKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine //to use Just

struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: AddViewModel = AddViewModel()
@FetchRequest(
            entity: UserSettings.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [])
    private var userSettingEntity: FetchedResults<UserSettings>


init(){


let x = viewModel.fetchProgresses()
let y = userSettingEntity.count

print(y)
print(x.count)
if(!x.isEmpty){
    print(x[0].bmr)



userName = x[0].firstName!
  ageInputString = String(x[0].age)
  heightInputString = String(x[0].height)
  weightInputString = String(x[0].weight)
  selectedGender = Double(x[0].age)
  chosenActivityLevel = x[0].activityLevel!
  BMR = x[0].bmr
    
    }
}
   

    var body: some View {

    
    VStack{ //vertical stack for the form
        Form{
            Section{
                Text(String(BMR))
    }

Any help would be really useful :)
```

For context here is my viewmodel:

```
class AddViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var userSettings = [UserSettings]()

    
    init() {
    //    print(fetchProgresses().count)

    }
    
    //Creating the data
    func addCalorieTrackerDate(id: UUID, firstName: String, height: Double, weight: Double, gender: String, age: Double, activityLevel: String, bmr: Double) {
        CoreDataManager.shared.addUserSettingsData(id: id, firstName: firstName, height: height, weight: weight, gender: gender, age: age, activityLevel: activityLevel, bmr: bmr) { (isAdded, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print("Data has been added!")
                print(gender)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //fetching the data
    func fetchProgresses() -> [UserSettings] {
        CoreDataManager.shared.fetchCalorieTrackerData { (userSettings, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let userSettings = userSettings as? [UserSettings] {
                self.userSettings = userSettings
            }
        }
        return userSettings
    }
```

CoreDataManager.swift:

```
class CoreDataManager {
    
    static let shared: CoreDataManager = {
        let appDelegate = AppDelegate.instance!
        let instance = CoreDataManager(managedObjectContext: appDelegate.persistanceContainer.viewContext)
        return instance
    }()
    
    var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    
  private init(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        managedContext = managedObjectContext
    }
}

//MARK:- CalorieTracker Insert/Update/Delete
extension CoreDataManager {
    func addUserSettingsData(id: UUID, firstName: String, height: Double, weight: Double, gender: String, age: Double, activityLevel: String, bmr: Double, completionHandler: @escaping (_ succeed: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        let userSettingsEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "UserSettings", into: managedContext) as? UserSettings
        userSettingsEntity?.id = id
        userSettingsEntity?.firstName = firstName
        userSettingsEntity?.height = height
        userSettingsEntity?.weight = weight
        userSettingsEntity?.gender = gender
        userSettingsEntity?.age = age
        userSettingsEntity?.activityLevel = activityLevel
        userSettingsEntity?.bmr = bmr
        
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            completionHandler(true, nil)
        } catch let error {
            completionHandler(false, error)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchCalorieTrackerData(completionHandler: @escaping (_ succeed: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        var progresses = [UserSettings]()
        let progressRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserSettings> = NSFetchRequest<UserSettings>(entityName: "UserSettings")
        
        do {
            progresses = try managedContext.fetch(progressRequest)
            completionHandler(progresses, nil)
        } catch let error {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteUserSettingData(){
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserSettings")
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    
        do {
            try managedContext.execute(deleteRequest)
        } catch _ as NSError {
    }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what code is in your view model and what code is in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing similar things in different places so it would be good to refactor this and have one source of data.

In the view model change `fetchProgresses` so it doesn't return anything so you will use the published property `userSettings` instead from your view.

Then in the view remove the fetch request and the init stuff and as mentioned get your data from the view model instead

```
struct ProfileView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: AddViewModel = AddViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{  
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text(String(viewModel.userSettings.first?.bmr ?? 0))
```

Are you always only getting one item in your UserSettings array since you are using a Form here rather than a List? If so then you should fix this in your view model by changing the published property to

```
@Published var userSettings: UserSettings?
```

or even better if you want to make this into more correct MVVM then have a published property for each property in UserSettings

```
@Published var firstName: String
@Published var bmr: String
...
```

then your view code would be simpler

Comment: After changing my ViewModel not to return anything, I am testing the way you mentioned to get values, however whenever i print(viewModel.userSettings.first.firstName) it prints nil. And also does not work in text views which is odd because the data definitely got inputted.

Comment: For some reason viewModel.userSettings is always empty which is strange

Comment: Have you debugged this (or added print statements) and stepped through fetchCalorieTrackerData and fetchProgresses to verify data is properly fetched?

Comment: Oddly your method of getting the value works well if I leave the viewModel with the type [userSettings]. Would you suggest using this if it works?

Comment: 'The preferred solution is of course to not use an array if you only have one object but it's your call.